# Does goddess Lalita have her own loka?

Tags: shiva, devi, lokas

I have heard about Vaikuntha for Vishnu etc.. Does devi Lalita and Lord Shiva have separate regions/lokas outside this mortal world? What is the name?

Comment: There's Shivaloka for Shiva!

Comment: @AkshayS is this Shiva loka separate from Mani dvipa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The abode of Sri Devi is known as [Mani Dvipa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manidvipa). Wikipedia states:

> In the Devi Bhagavatam, Manidweepa portrayed as the Sarvaloka
>   superior to Kailasa, Vaikunta and Goloka. Devi
>   Bhuvaneshvari/Tripurasundari is the Empress of Manidvipa. At the
>   beginning of the creation, Devi Adi Parashakti-Mahakali created this
>   island.

Quoting from the book ["Essence of Devi Bhagavatam"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana79.html):

> **Being far superior to Kailasa, Vaikuntha and Goloka, the Sarvaloka or Mani Dvipa is the residence of Devi Bhagavati in whom the entire
>   Creation rests! Indeed She resides everywhere and anywhere but
>   notionally at Mani Dvipa** and the description is transcripted in
>   detail by Maharshi Veda Vyasa apparenly for the consumption of mortals
>   to carry conviction into their consciousness. Surrounded by ‘Sudha
>   Sagara’ ( The Ocean of Nectar), Manidvipa has a strong iron enclosure
>   of several Yojanas far and wide with four gates well guarded by Devas
>   and Devis. Within the First Enclosure, there is an Enlosure of white
>   metal made of an amalgam of zinc and tin/copper which touches Heavens
>   and is hundred times higher than the walls of the outer Enclosure.This
>   Enclosure is interspersed with gardens and forests with a wide range
>   of trees and plants, flowers with intoxicating fragrances, luscious
>   fruits along with streams of fruit juices and gregarious animals and
>   birds of staggering variety. The third Enclosure is made of copper
>   with a height of seven yojanas comprising several ‘Kalpavrikshas’,
>   with golden leaves/ flowers and fruits yielding gems, fulfilling
>   desires of any imagination.The King of the Gardens  along with the
>   wives Madhu Sri and Madhava Sri maintains an excellent Spring Season,
>   where Gandharvas reside, rendering divinely songs and music. The
>   Fourth Enclosure made of lead with its wall height is again seven
>   yojanas and within the Enclosure are the Sanatanaka trees with flowers
>   whose fragrance reaches as far as ten yojanas and fresh fruits
>   providing sweet juices of great quality and its King with the two
>   queens Sukra Sri and Sudha Sri always maintains enjoyble mild summer
>   where Siddhas and Devas reside here

In this loka Lord Shiva (who is inseparable from Devi) also resides as Ardhanriswara.

Comment: can you provide link from full devi bhagavatam may be on archive so that I can also directly study the chapter?

Comment: You can read from [here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatamindex.htm) @MohMur and here is a PDF: http://upload.vedpuran.net/Uploads/68655SrimadDeviPurana.pdf

Comment: @MohMur http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/index.htm

Comment: @TheDestroyer which chapter has description of this loka?

Comment: @MohMur Last chapters of Book 12. http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/db03.htm If you have idea of Sri Chakra or Sri Vidya and its yogic meaning, you can relate description of Manidvipa more.